# Remover vários elementos de uma lista [COMMON LISP]

Tags: paradigma-de-programação, lisp

Quero remover vários elementos de uma lista e retornar a lista sem estes elementos.

```
(defun removeAll (lista1 lista2)
 .
 .
 .
)

Entrada: > (removeAll '(a b c) '(a b c d))

Saída; > (d)
```

Já pensei muito e não obtive sucesso, se alguém puder me nortear, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução no StackOverflow gringo, segue link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574567/lisp-how-to-remove-list-of-elements-from-list

Usando a função [SET-DIFFERENCE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_di.htm)

```
Entrada: > (set-difference '(a b c d) '(b c))
Saída: > (a d)
```